# Parallel and COM (Outlook MAPI) aqcuiring and releasing?

Tags: c#, com, task-parallel-library, exchange-server, mapi

Ive checked already some answers, but still Im not convinced what is this right approach of acquiring and releasing *COM* objects in parallel.

In particular I use a `Parallel.ForEach` to increase performance, and inside it, it makes calls to *MS.Outlook* (2010 ExchangeServer). However, by releasing the COM objects I get occasionally *COMExceptions*.

What is the right approach of working with *COM* objects with the `Parallel` library ?

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(myList, myItem =>
{
     String freeBusySlots = "";
     Outlook.Recipient myReceipient = null;

     try
     {
         myReceipient = namespaceMAPI.CreateRecipient(myItem.ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ...
     }
     finally
     {
        if (myReceipient == null)
        {
            ...
        }

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myReceipient ); // -> I get an exception here sometimes ... how to avoid this
        myReceipient = null;
     }
}); // Parllel.forEach
```

Answer (score 3):

Outlook Object Model cannot be used from secondary threads. Sometimes it works, but it tends to bomb out at the most inappropriate moment.

As of Outlook 2013, Outlook will immediately raise an error if an OOM object is accessed from a secondary thread.

If your code is running from another application, keep in mind that all calls will be serialized to the main Outlook thread anyway so there is really no point using multiple threads.

Also note that Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (which wraps Extended MAPI and can be accessed from any language - I am its author) can be used from multiple threads, but your mileage will vary depending on the particular MAPI provider (IMAP4 store provider is the worst).

Comment: My code will be running from an Outlook Add-in. The idea is to parallelize to connections to the exchange server to reduce the load on it.
Any idea of how to make the above code with Redemption? How can I find out the particular MAPI provider ?

Comment: Is it suitable to switch from `MAPI` to `EWS` ? I use mainly the method `getFreeBusy` to contact the ExchangeServer.

Comment: Sure, EWS is pure HTTP, you can do that in a secondary thread.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you should never be using `ReleaseComObject`.  Instead just wait for the RCW object to be collected and let the GC do the work for you.  Using this API correctly is extremely hard.

Additionally it's very likely that all of Outlooks COM objects live in the STA.  If that is the case there is nothing gained by operating over them in parallel.  Every call made from a background thread will simply be marashalled back to the foreground thread for processing.  Hence the background thread will add no value, just confusion.

I'm not 100% certain these are STA objects but I'd be very surprised if they weren't.

Comment: ReleaseComObject is perfectly fine.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko no, it's a very dangerous API http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2010/03/08/marshal-relasecomobject-considered-not-very-nice.aspx

Comment: It is perfectly fine in this particular case. the variable is declared on the local level, you never reference it from the outside, and Outlook Object Model is written in unmanaged C++, not .Net. This is actually *the only way* to make it work if you process a large number of Outlook items - Exchange server limits the number of simultaneously open objects, and if you go over the limit it will refuse to open any more.

Comment: @JaredPar: 10x for answering. So, paralleling the access to the Outlok Exchange Server doesn't doesn't bring any gain. There is really no possible way to speed up the exchange server calls from my outlook add-in ?

Comment: You can use secondary threads in a COM addin as long as you are not touching the Outlook Object Model, which means only C++/Delphi or a wrapper like Redemption (RDO family of objects) are used.